# Air for Android app closes after approx 1 hour, possible memory leak?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, logcat

I have an Air app that needs to viably run 24/7.

The app closes itself without warning after approximately 1 hour, running on an Android TV Stick.

Here are my logcat readings:

> I/ActivityManager( 1234):               211911 kB: air.mycompany.myapp
>   (pid 7629)
>
> I/ActivityManager( 1234):  7629  238272K  224692K  208012K  205652K 
>   air.mycompany.myapp
>
> I/ActivityManager( 1234): Process air.mycompany.myapp (pid 7629) has
>   died.
>
> W/ActivityManager( 1234): Force removing ActivityRecord{41378f50
>   air.mycompany.myapp/.AppEntry}: app died, no saved state
>
> I/WindowManager( 1234): WIN DEATH: Window{412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry paused=false}
>
> W/InputDispatcher( 1234): channel '412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry (server)' ~ Consumer
>   closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
>
> E/InputDispatcher( 1234): channel '412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry (server)' ~ Channel
>   is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>
> W/InputDispatcher( 1234): Attempted to unregister already unregistered
>   input channel '412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry (server)'
>
> W/WindowManager( 1234): Force-removing child win Window{41390cd8
>   SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry paused=false}
>
> W/WindowManager( 1234): Force-removing child win Window{4137d548
>   SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry paused=false}
>
> I/WindowManager( 1234): WINDOW DIED Window{412e5718
>   air.mycompany.myapp/air.mycompany.myapp.AppEntry paused=false}

First thoughts are that it is a memory leak (something i am trying to figure out, im cycling through movieclips and i think they are stakcing up in the memory rather then being reused properly)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your logging does not seem to have started early enough to capture the source of the problem.  If it will occur with ADB connected, consider streaming the logcat log to disk on your development machine (it will be a rather large file) during a test session so that you can look backwards in time for clues to the ultimate cause of the crash.

Comment: What would be the cause for the logging not to have started early enough? I thought logging started up automatically on Android? All's I did was download a log.cat reader after the crash in order to find this error. These were the only messages showing my app after a search. Weird.

Comment: The log runs the whole time, but old messages get discarded to make room for new ones.  Running the logcat tool on your development machine, especially piping it into a disk file, will let you see the entire history.  When you see clear indication that the crash is happening, start looking back earlier for something that might have triggered it.

Comment: The issue only arises on this TV Stick. Is there a good app for recording log.cat? Without needing root? (The one I downloaded simply let you read it and do a basic search, so its pretty useless in this case)

Comment: An app is really not the best way to do it, use the sdk tools on your development machine.  But if your device is old enough to allow apps to access logcat, you can just do it from a terminal program such as connectbot.